# Immutable val null check inside extension function

Tags: kotlin

When I have an immutable val optional, the compiler tracks the information about the check I performed for null and can treat the variable as non null and call it directly inside the if condition.

```
val s: String? = "test"

if (s != null) {
   s.startsWith("3") // This works
}

if (!s.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    s.startsWith("3") // Not working
}
```

Is it possible to make that check in an extension function and keep the compiler aware of it?

Comment: Basically you are asking for contracts, which are not yet available. See https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/status-of-kotlin-internal-contracts/6392/3 and https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/kotlin-contracts.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not yet available in Kotlin.

There is a feature called "Contracts" which is currently developed at JetBrains (https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/status-of-kotlin-internal-contracts/6392) – it's similar to what they've done with [their own `@Contract` annotation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html) for Java code, but will have support from the compiler.

However, it's in early stages and there is no release date yet.